# Is this SQL Injection?

Tags: sql-injection, code-injection

I have been sent emails and had some suspicious activity in my database (like every link clicked but no information passing through) and then from the subscribers email form (which a hacker would think would be going into a database - but its not).

I have received two emails with differing web addresses on the end. So I am wondering what this is? Also I checked the IP address and it had some kind of virus.

He put an email in the email field, a name in the name field, and the website address in the comments section, the dots are mine. I changed the number in the email address in case it is a real person and not a hacker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not SQL Injection, well at least in the normal definition of the term. Allow me to explain:

A SQL injection is a carefully structured string that contains SQL commands that are sent to a vulnerable website.  The data you show does not contain any SQL commands, just gibberish.

What you see is very common "spam bot" type of spider that is checking to see if it can use forms on your website to send out spam messages of its own.  I get these on my web-forms all the time.  There are many solutions to handle this, but that is a little off-topic here.